# Order status link with sensitive data (no auth/login)

Tags: php, laravel

After every order in custom webshop I'm sending link to order status for my clients.

As of right now I'm sending Crypted:: (Laravel) parameters as a link and not registered users can check order status. It's hard to crack but one downside is link length. It can be something like that:

```
https://mywebsite.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
```

Quite a long url. I'm thinking what can I do about that. Making random character UID stored with every order and making that UID as link to order status will be a better option? What about security of that link? Should I crypt parameters like always and UID can be made from md5 of that crypt or that's not nessesery and any random X lenght string will be enough?

What about something like that?

```
public function order(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'card_value' => 'required|integer|max:500|min:50',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($request->get('finalize')) {
        $order = VoucherOrder::create([
            'value' => $request->get('card_value'),
            'price' => $request->get('card_value'),
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
        ]);

        $parameters =[
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'date' => Carbon::now(),
            'type' => 'voucher_order',
        ];

        $order->uid = md5(Crypt::encrypt($parameters));

        $order->save();

        SendVoucherOrderConfirmation::dispatch($order)->onQueue('high');
    }
}
```

Am I wrong or shorter md5 from Crypt:: will be at the same level hard to guess as any random 32 characters string?

Comment: Why exactly are you encrypting the uid?

Comment: @UzairRiaz inside order status there are users sensitive data so I'm trying to be as far from random number inside public url as possible.

Comment: Hmm, if it contains sensitive data, why not just make it accessible for a user only?

Comment: @UzairRiaz 70% of orders are not related to any account and never come back after initial purchase. So making additional step in webshop is not an option.

Comment: UID is not easy to guess either so I guess that would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

Ideally your clients have an account on you page. Then each order has an ID in the database, and you can send out a link like this: `https://mywebsite.com/order/status/<orderID>`. When the client clicks on the link then you also have to check if the order belongs to the user or not. For this you have to store a user_id field with the order in the database.

A bit better if you use a unique hash - maybe 8-16 character long, instead of the OrderID parameter in the link, so the clients and other companies wont know about the popularity of your website by knowing how much orders did you proceed so far.

The other case is when you let users with no account to buy. This case is also not totally hopeless, because you are sending email to them about their order. For this you need to validate their email, by sending them a validation email, and then you can create a user in your database for that email and then proceed with the same solution above.

You can also skip the email validation part, but the problem with this is if the user is missing a character while giving you the email address, then the email wont go anywhere, or in worst case someone else will get the email.

But as soon as you are sure that you have the user's correct email address you can create the a user in your database and have permission checks attached to the end point, which you send to the user as link.

Comment: Yes that's pretty simply idea of auth, order numbers and you are also right if user make a mistek in order e-mail that order will be lost. But in my question I'm super confident that orders have to be made without accounts too... so with that crypt link all works ok and secure... but I'm thinking how to make shorter links and still maintain security level for not logged in users.

Comment: In that case you can still create a user in your database with that email, the user provides you. The user doesn't have to register, you would only create the user in the database, because with that you can validate the user from the link, where you place the orderID or the hash

Comment: the point to the trick is that each email address is unique. And at the point when the user gives away his/her email address, then you can use this personal information as the tracker of the order, by creating a user in your database. Downside is; if the user gives you fake email, or makes a typo in the email, then the email can be duplicated, but you already know this part.

Comment: Not perfect solution because still I need to make accounts and account without password or sth to authenticate is worthless because on public links someone can enter other customer e-mail and get theirs order status. Idea with crypted link is that only that customer have that link in his inbox and can check order status. Crypted link can't be cracked from outside. Problem is with that length and by shortening that crypto in my opinion ther's no any benefits between md5 crypto then random 32 characters variable.